# List Items being rendered in the same spot instead of vertically/horizontally

Tags: html, css

I'm curious as to what in my styling is causing this issue. I have three columns in each colcontainer, and all the `<li>`s are jumbling into each other like it was position: absolute. I just want them to stack vertically like they normally do. Anyone have any ideas?

CSS:

```
#slider .colcontainer {
    width: 600px;
    height: 200px;
    background: red;
    float: left;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
#slider .col1 {
    width: 30%;
    margin-left: 1.5%;
    margin-right: 1.5%;
    background: blue;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}
#slider .col1 ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    float: none;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="colcontainer">
                    <div class="col1">
                        <ul>
                            <li>Test</li>
                            <li>Test</li>
                            <li>Test</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col1">
                        <ul>
                            <li>Test</li>
                            <li>Test</li>
                            <li>Test</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col1">
                        <ul>
                            <li>Test</li>
                            <li>Test</li>
                            <li>Test</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: There's no `#slider` in your HTML.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have #slider in your code, so your styles are not applied.

http://jsfiddle.net/EZx3b/

```
.colcontainer {
    width: 600px;
    height: 200px;
    background: red;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.col1 {
    width: 30%;
    margin-left: 1.5%;
    margin-right: 1.5%;
    background: blue;
    float: left;
    overflow: auto;
}
.col1 ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, slider is in there, I just cut out the relevant code so as to not have a big paste. These are all contained in slider.

Comment: Then it's not clear what the problem is. Your code works nicely in the demo.

Answer (score 0):

I would start by setting:

```
#slider li {
  display:block;
  position:static;
}
```

If that doesn't work, you should inspect the element in Firebug or Chrome Inspector and see which rules are overriding it and messing up the display.

Answer (score 0):

I wrapped your `colcontainer` into yet another `div#slider`, but there's no problem so far. Three columns with three items.

See [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/64GnT/)